# clean csv file from hidden characters

Tags: hidden-characters

I work with CSV files and upload them to an S3 server.
Sometimes after a small process that I did with the file I get hidden characters to look like this ∩╗┐ before the first columns, I want to write a script that "clean" the files before upload but I can see those characters only on specific text editors like nano, the python didn't recognize those characters and I can see them in Amazon Athena after the query was created already and I need to upload it again.
Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: The characters you've shown don't look like "hidden" to me. Why not check where they are coming from and block that, instead of removing them afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

After a small research I learn that the symbol called BOM and they added to the files because I added `encoding='utf-8'`.